# IE11 onClick event is not working for dojo components

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-11

We developed our application using Dojo in IE8 now we are moving it to IE11.When we run the application, Click event is triggered only for button and check box.When i click on the text box, it does not focuses or any other components.

Any suggestion/help why is it behaving like this.

Comment: More information could be usefull, which version of Dojo are you using? How do you listen for and catch events? A code example and/or live testcase on Plunker maybe?

Comment: we are using dojo 1.9.1 currently.

Comment: no manual listen for and catch events are handled. It is using the inbuild events. we will be taking the value by selection made using click

Comment: Why aren't you using the current version 1.10??? See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/releasenotes/1.10.html#releasenotes-1-10

Comment: we are using dojo 1.10.2 latest release only. then also we are facing the issue.Could you give any suggestions

Comment: Onclick events are triggering but the selection in the multiselect is not happening. onclicking on the multiselect value no value is getting selected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you said you're using Dojo 1.9.1. However, when I read the blogpost about Dojo 1.9.2, I see:

> Dojo version 1.9.2 is now available for immediate use. The most
>   prominent changes are:
>
> - Support for IE11
> - Support for W3C Pointer Events API in touch-enabled components (necessary for IE11 support)
> - Fixes for modern Firefox and Chrome
> - Fixes to star-mapping and aliases when using built layers
> - Fixes to sorting Date objects in dojo/store/Memory and other stores that use SimpleQueryEngine
> - Fixes to Dijit pop-up scrolling when using the scrollbar

Reference: [Dojo 1.9.2 and more](http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/dojo-1-9-2-and-more)

Try to run your application with Dojo 1.9.2 first. Since you're already using Dojo 1.9.1, the switch to 1.9.2 should not be too hard I suppose, because it's a patch version.